# Auto Hot Key - Holding down one key holds down 2 different keys

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

So I've used AutoHotKey to disable the AppsKey (the button on the keyboard which brings up the right-click menu). But I thought I could put it to better to use, and am trying to get it so that while I'm holding down the AppsKey the computer thinks I'm holding down Shift & Control instead.

I've been reading through the [Command List](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands.htm) but can't see anything for AppsKey down & up. Would anyone be able to share anything to enable me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems? Since you already wrote a script, I assume you know how to remap *AppsKey*.

Comment: My script is just currently `AppsKey::return`.

Comment: There you go! Now, instead of only `return`, you'll have to `Send` something; see the correspondent command. Also, here's [how to create hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Comment: But that would just be a single key press, not a hold down command. I could send `{Control down}` but then I wouldn't be able to send a `{Control up}` command as I can't find an `AppsKey up` or `down`.

Comment: You want `AppsKey` to result in `SHIFT + CTRL`, don't you? If so, just have a look at the link I posted, there are plenty of examples. If you want `SHIFT + CTRL` to be held down as long as `AppsKey` is held down, that's something else then. But still, the docs should show you how to achieve that.

Comment: I want `Shift + Ctrl` as long as AppsKey is held down. There is no AppsKey Up or AppsKey Down (At least, I cannot get it to work. It keeps saying there is an error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what your problems are, but this little piece of code works for me:

```
AppsKey::Send, {SHIFT down}{CTRL down}
AppsKey up::Send, {CTRL up}{SHIFT up}
```

As you can see, there **is** an `AppsKey up`. `Down` on the other hand doesn't exist for hotkeys. In this example, the first hotkey triggers when `AppsKey` is pressed (that is, it triggers as soon as you hit it). The second hotkey triggers when it is released.

Comment: Thanks, this does work. I didn't know there wasn't an AppsKey down and that was giving the error.